# Custom Resolution at 144hz refresh rate

Tags: windows, graphics-card, resolution

I'm trying to run a videogame (CS:GO) at a custom resolution (1440x1080) lower then my native resolution (1920x1080) while maintaining the 144hz refresh rate my monitor provides. However, whenever the game changes to this resolution the refresh rate drops to 60hz. The game allows for launch parameters to force it running at a specific refreshrate but this does not seem to work.

Is anyone able to explain to me why this is not working and/or tell me how to make this work?

- **Monitor:** Asus VG248QE
- **GPU:** AMD R9 Fury X
- **Driver Software:** Catalyst Control Center

Answer (score 1):

ASUS only guarantees that the monitor will work on 144hz at 1920x1080. I think it would crash or wouldnt give you a picture at all if you managed to force it on 144hz at 1440x1080. Why do you want to run it under 1080p? The R9 Fury X can easily blast out 144 fps even on full max settings.

Comment: The reason for lowering the resolution is to allow more focus to the center of the game. There are multiple reasons to lower the resolution. Performance is one of them but not the reason to do it for me. It will allow me to concentrate better and have a more compact view overall. Thank you for your response!